# Problems with loading a map with bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to load a map with the bukkit API, and ran into a problem.
The map does not load. The file gets created and get cappied as well, but when i do /memory in game, it shows all the loaded worlds, and this does not show up. And when i try to teleport to the world by doing `p.teleport(world.getSpawnLocation());` it just throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` execption.

my code:

```
 public static void loadMap(String l) throws IOException {
        try {
            File folderName = new File(plugin.getDataFolder() + "/maps/Dungeon");
            File desti = new File(l + "_world");
            if(!desti.exists()) {
                desti.mkdir();
            }
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(folderName, desti);
            World world = Bukkit.getServer().createWorld(new WorldCreator(l + "_world"));
            System.out.println("[DDEBUG]" + world);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

that means the player is null, so it throws this error
btw. if you use try and catch blok, so remove throws IOException